# puede enviar codeigniter un formulario sin el atributo de action?

Tags: codeigniter, codeigniter-3

Hola soy realmente nuevo en codeigniter y empecé con la versión 6, encontré un codigo de login que me gustó pero no encuentro a qué controlador o página lo envía, he trabajado principalmente con laravel y no tengo problemas para entenderle, pero con este me está costando.

```
<div class="modal fade" id="login-modal" tabindex="-1" role="dialog">
       <div class="modal-dialog">
            <div class="loginmodal-container">
               <?php if($this->setting->logo){ ?><img src="<?=base_url()?>files/Setting/<?=$this->setting->logo;?>" alt="logo"  style='max-height: 45px; max-width: 200px; margin: 0 auto'><?php } else { ?><img src="<?=base_url()?>assets/img/logo.png" alt="logo"><?php } ?>
               <h1><?=label('Loginaccount');?></h1><br>
               <?php if(isset($message)){echo "<div class='red'>".$message."</div>";}?>
               <?php
              $attributes = array('class' => 'login');
              echo form_open('login', $attributes);
              ?>
               <input type="text" autofocus name="username" value="<?=isset($username)?$username:''?>" placeholder="<?=label("Username");?>" required>
               <input type="password" name="password" placeholder="<?=label("Password");?>" required>
               <?php
                  echo form_submit('submit', label("Login"), "class='login loginmodal-submit'");
               ?>

              <?=form_close()?>

              <div class="login-help">
               &copy; <?=date("Y");?> <?=$this->setting->companyname?>
              </div>
            </div>
         </div>
       </div>




      <!-- jQuery -->
      <script type="text/javascript" src="<?=base_url()?>assets/js/jquery-2.2.2.min.js"></script>
      <!-- waves material design effect -->
      <script type="text/javascript" src="<?=base_url()?>assets/js/waves.min.js"></script>
      <!-- Bootstrap Core JavaScript -->
      <script type="text/javascript" src="<?=base_url()?>assets/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>

      <script type="text/javascript">
      $(document).ready(function() {
         $('#login-modal').modal('show').on('hide.bs.modal', function (e) {
            e.preventDefault();
         });
      });
      </script>
   </body>
```

Comment: Sí se puede, solo debes hacer un endpoint y hacer uso de AJAX para hacer ese tipo de peticiones.

Comment: pero eso está en este codigo? ya que nunca he hecho algo similar pero no hay algo que me dé a entender eso

Comment: La verdad es que sí, estás capturando el id de login-modal y haces un prevent default. Solo debes buscar cómo mandar esa petición a tu endpoint y está te devolverá una respuesta.

Comment: fijate que lo pensé pero como no hay ningún archivo js que me dé a entender que es independiente de los frameworks, pero ahorita analizado el codigo, me doy cuenta de que no está mandando el password, solo el username

Answer (score 0):

Si no pones action en un form lo que hace es ir a la funcion que ha cargado la vista para que se vea el formulario

Si en esa funcion pones:

```
if (!empty($_POST) && $_POST) {
    //aqui procesas el formulario
}
```

Esto si el formulario se envia por post, si se envia por get pues $_GET